# Android: Spinner background in datepicker

Tags: android, background-color, android-datepicker

I want the background of datepicker in spinner view as opaque white. I tried applying background property to datepicker as white (#1000), but the datepicker background is still transparent and the controls which are on the same screen seems to be overlapped by datepicker. Therefore, I need to set the datepicker background to pure white (fully opaque). How?

Comment: Wouldn't opaque white would be #FFFFFFFF?

Comment: Is it...??  Because i thought 1 would be for alpha and the leading 3 zeros for RGB..  Well, i'll use your combination as well and get back with the result. Thanks . .